# React PWA detect new content on iOS is not working as expected

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, typescript, progressive-web-apps

I use CRA PWA and add toast that's show when onupdatefound and onstatechange. it's working well in android and pc but in iOS it's not shown and content not refresh till close tab and open it again.

I searching long time and not found any good answer for this issue.

I have ServiceWorkerWrapper.ts

```
import React, { FC, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Snackbar, Button } from '@material-ui/core';
import * as serviceWorker from '../serviceWorkerRegistration';

const ServiceWorkerWrapper: FC = () => {
  const [showReload, setShowReload] = React.useState(false);
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer:any;
    if (counter >= 0 && showReload) {
      setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000)
    } else if (showReload) {
      reloadPage();
    }
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [counter]);

  const onSWUpdate = (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => {
    if (registration && registration.waiting) {
      setShowReload(true);
      setCounter(2)
    } else {
      setShowReload(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    serviceWorker.register({ onUpdate: onSWUpdate });
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const reloadPage = () => {
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .getRegistration()
        .then((reg:any) => {
          reg.waiting.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
          window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('Could not get registration: ', err));
    }
  };

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={showReload}
      message="A new version is available!"
      onClick={reloadPage}
      ContentProps={{
        className: "reload-snackbar"
      }}
      anchorOrigin={{ vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'center' }}
      action={
        <Button
          color="inherit"
          size="small"
          onClick={reloadPage}
        >
          Reload{showReload ? ` (${counter + 1})`:''}
        </Button>
      }
    />
  );
}

export default ServiceWorkerWrapper;
```

serviceWorkerRegistration.ts

```
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read https://cra.link/PWA

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/)
);

type Config = {
  onSuccess?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
  onUpdate?: (registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration) => void;
};

export function register(config?: Config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit https://cra.link/PWA'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      if (navigator.vendor === 'Apple Computer, Inc.') {
                console.log('Safari!!!!');
                if (registration.waiting) {
                    if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                        config.onUpdate(registration);
                    }
                }
            }
      
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed.'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl: string, config?: Config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.');
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}
```

service-worker.ts

```
/// <reference lib="webworker" />
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */

// This service worker can be customized!
// See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules
// for the list of available Workbox modules, or add any other
// code you'd like.
// You can also remove this file if you'd prefer not to use a
// service worker, and the Workbox build step will be skipped.

import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';

declare const self: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope;

clientsClaim();

// Precache all of the assets generated by your build process.
// Their URLs are injected into the manifest variable below.
// This variable must be present somewhere in your service worker file,
// even if you decide not to use precaching. See https://cra.link/PWA
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

// Set up App Shell-style routing, so that all navigation requests
// are fulfilled with your index.html shell. Learn more at
// https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell
const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }: { request: Request; url: URL }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    }

    // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    }

    // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains
    // a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    }

    // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.
    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/index.html')
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'),
  // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      // Ensure that once this runtime cache reaches a maximum size the
      // least-recently used images are removed.
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);

// This allows the web app to trigger skipWaiting via
// registration.waiting.postMessage({type: 'SKIP_WAITING'})
self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

// Any other custom service worker logic can go here.
```